# How to search through a string with an array of strings (js)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

What Im trying to do is the example below (except for the part where it doesnt work):
I want to filter through a string (Message), where it checks for an array of strings (Exception), with outcome true (for any of the strings from the array) or false (if there are none of the strings from the array).
I cant figure out how to make this work, as most information i find seems to do only the opposite (search through an array of strings with a single string).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
var Message = "i bought a pear";
const Trigger = "bought";
const Exception = ["apple", "pear", "banana"]

if ((Message.includes(Trigger)) && (!Message.includes(Exception))) {
    console.log("Trigger hit!");                                         
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate the `exception` array and check the message.

```js
const
    message = "i bought a pear",
    trigger = "bought",
    exception = ["apple", "pear", "banana"];

if (message.includes(trigger) && !exception.some(e => message.includes(e))) {
    console.log("Trigger hit!");                                         
}

console.log(exception.some(e => message.includes(e))); // true
```

Comment: Perhaps your solution is 'nicer' than mine; maybe add some toLowerCase() to it so it checks regardless of upper/lowercase difference.

Just to add as a note: I think str.includes() would check if not the whole word matches exactly, but is included within. "applejuice" would be true on 'apple'.

Comment: for an exact check, regex would be better.

Answer (score 0):

```
    let message = "i bought a pear";
    const trigger = "bought";
    const exceptions = ["apple", "pear", "banana"];

    let newMessageArr = message.split(' ');
    exceptions.forEach((exception) => {
        console.log(exception);
        newMessageArr.forEach(word => {
            if( word === exception )
                console.log("true");
        })
    })
```